# What's the meaning of "you are a shell"?

Tags: vocabulary, lyrics

This is an excerpt from the song "Full Circle" by Creed:

> Keep burning bridges while you're buying your new friends
>
> A day of reflection hits, **you're a shell**, skin and bones, counting costs
>
> Is it worth your soul?

From my understanding, the lyrics say that this person is "skin and bones" and "counting costs" because they've used all their money to impress his/her new friends, right? What does *being a shell* mean though?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Generally, when a person is "in a shell", it means that they are reclusive, unresponsive, even antisocial.

Comment: But the song doesn't say "you are in a shell". It says "you are a shell". Do you not see a distinction between being a house and being in a house?

Comment: oops...you are correct... I read it too fast, I would say that, since the following adjective phrase is "skin and bones", the person is then commenting on the person's physical appearance.

Comment: You still misinterpret.  The words are a metaphor.  Has nothing to do with appearance.

Answer (score 7):

"To be a shell" means to be hollow, with nothing inside. So the subject of the song is "skin and bones" which determine his exterior, but has no internal substance, no soul.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

To be a shell is to have no soul, no character, and to live only for the approval of others.  You "Keep burning bridges while you're buying your new friends" Breaking real friendships, and buying popularity, but there is no substance. "A day of reflection hits, you're a shell"  Is all the fame and popularity... "Is it worth your soul?"